# Dart authentication registration

Tags: django, authentication, dart

I am building a single page javascript app using dart, what are the recommended ways to handle user authentication and registration?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dart-client/ for information about using oAuth with Dart.

I noticed that you tagged this with `django`. I'm assuming then that you are using Django in some way. If that is the case, can you not use the authentication provided by Django itself?

Answer (score 0):

There is now the easy to use [Google OAuth2 Library, which you can get from Pub](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_oauth2_client).

[Here is a great guide on how to use the package from Dartwatch](http://blog.dartwatch.com/2013/04/sign-in-with-google-using-google-oauth2.html).